# HTML/CSS: Overlay an empty div over a canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I would like to overlay an empty div over a canvas to create some kind of vignette effect.

Now for some reason, the vignette div is not visible at all. If I place some text inside of the vingette div, it becomes visible, but only, if I also remove the height property from the vignette class.

Is there some way to just display the empty div on top of the canvas and scale its height and width to 100%?

My code so far:

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.container canvas,
.vignette {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.vignette {
    background: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 50%, black 150%);
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <canvas id="game-screen"></canvas>
        <div class="vignette"></div>
    </div
```

Comment: Your container does not have any height, because you positioned all of its children absolutely. 100% of zero is still zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should insert

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

and for `.container` add:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container canvas,
.vignette {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.vignette {
    background: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 50%, black 150%);
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <canvas id="game-screen"></canvas>
        <div class="vignette"></div>
    </div
```